# How to make TextFieldTableCell conditional on model property?

Tags: javafx

I have a `TableView` with an editable `TextFieldTableCell` that I want to restrict to be available based on a `BooleanProperty` of my model object.

For example, `textField.disableProperty().bind(item.editableProperty().not())`

Currently, I have the basic implementation from the Oracle docs:

```
colComment.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
colComment.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView().getItems().get(
    event.getTablePosition().getRow()).setComment(
    event.getNewValue())
);
```

This obviously does not allow much flexibility. The desire is to check the item's `editableProperty` and if it is `true`, display the `TextFieldTableCell` and bind it to the item's `commentProperty`.

If that property is `false`, the cell should simply display the value of the `commentProperty`.

I have not worked with editable TableViews in the past so I am a bit lost.

I have tried to hack out a workaround with manually setting the graphic myself, but that just does nothing with the cell:

```
colComment.setCellFactory(cell -> new TableCell<LogEntry, String>() {

    final TextField txtComment = new TextField();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            LogEntry logEntry = (LogEntry) getTableRow().getItem();
            if (logEntry.isEditable()) {
                txtComment.textProperty().bindBidirectional(logEntry.commentProperty());
                setGraphic(txtComment);
            } else {
                setText(item);
            }
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: why not simply bind the cell's editability to the logEntry's editable property? Anyway, the hack-around is definitely wrong because it slips under the feet of the editing mechanism: you __must not__ change the data from anywhere in the cell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach is to disallow cell's editing based on a condition. TextFieldTableCell has no direct support for such, but can be extended just as any other type of cell. Options are

- override startEdit to do nothing if the condition is not met
- bind the cell's editability property to a condition of the rowItem

The most simple is the first (the latter is a bit more involved, due to requiring updates when parent TableRow and its item changes). A quick example (all boiler-plate except the cell ;):

```
public class TableCellConditionalEditable extends Application {
    
    /**
     * Cell with custom condition to prevent editing.
     */
    public static class ConditionalEditableCell extends TextFieldTableCell<ConditionalWritable, String> {
        
        public ConditionalEditableCell() {
            super(new DefaultStringConverter());
        }

        /** 
         * Overridden to do nothing if rowItem-related condition not met.
         */
        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isConditionalEditable()) return;
            super.startEdit();
        }

       private boolean isConditionalEditable() {
            if (getTableRow() == null || getTableRow().getItem() == null || isEmpty()) return false;
            return getTableRow().getItem().writableProperty().get();
        }
        
    }
    
    private Parent createContent() {
        TableView<ConditionalWritable> table = new TableView<>(ConditionalWritable.conditionalWritables());
        TableColumn<ConditionalWritable, String> text = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        text.setCellValueFactory(cc -> cc.getValue().textProperty());
        TableColumn<ConditionalWritable, Boolean> writable = new TableColumn<>("Writable");
        writable.setCellValueFactory(cc -> cc.getValue().writableProperty());
        table.getColumns().addAll(text, writable);
        
        table.setEditable(true);
        text.setCellFactory(cc -> new ConditionalEditableCell());
        
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class ConditionalWritable {
        
        private SimpleStringProperty text;
        private SimpleBooleanProperty writable;

        public ConditionalWritable(String text, boolean writable) {
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
            this.writable = new SimpleBooleanProperty(writable);
        }
        
        public StringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }
        
        public BooleanProperty writableProperty() {
            return writable;
        }
        
        public static ObservableList<ConditionalWritable> conditionalWritables() {
            return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new ConditionalWritable("some data", false),  
                    new ConditionalWritable("other data", true),  
                    new ConditionalWritable("nothing important", true)  
                    );
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible, with this method, to always display the TextField without having to double-click the row to start editing?

Comment: not directly with TextFieldTableCell (going dirty wouldn't help overly much) - you would have to implement your own (and probably use the second option to bind the cell/textField editability to model state). It's a bit of work to get it right but straightforward enough (I assume :)

Comment: @Zephyr Use this answer to always show a text field https://stackoverflow.com/a/50408920/9278333